# Issue Seperate Arguments to Exe in one construct

Tags: c#, adb

I'm currently trying to pipe multiple parameters to the `adb.exe` file in the google sdk. an example of my inputs are:

> adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
>
> adb shell getprop ro.product.brand

which are outputting correct from my application. Though, the problem is I want to populate a list view of information, the problem that i'm currently encountering though, is the method to pipe commands to get desired output. I've currently got:

```
 var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "Resources/adb.exe",
                    Arguments = "devices",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            string Output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

This currently returns as expected, but i'm wishing to get multiple results from piping something like:

```
Arguments = "devices ro.build.version.release ro.product.brand"
```

This provides no avail, even when piping directly into command prompt.

> adb shell getprop devices ro.build.version.release ro.product.brand

empty, I have come around with a (assumingly) load heavy solution, which is to move the initialization of the executional into it's own function to be called multiple times. See code below:

```
    public string GetInfo(string CommandArg)
    {
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "Resources/adb.exe",
                Arguments = CommandArg,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
        return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    }


    public void SetDefineInformation()
    {
        AndroidVersion = decimal.Parse(GetInfo("ro.build.version.release"));
        DeviceModel = GetInfo("ro.product.device");
        ...
    }
```

To me, this seems like a load heavy task with constantly opening a single executable for it to close then re-open until the task is complete. Is there an overall work around, which might allow one to pipe multiple parameters to an executional and get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb can start a shell so you could create the shell with `adb shell` then [redirect stdin and stdout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) to write to it directly

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will definitely look into this method!

Answer (score 1):

No measurable performance gain would come from the "optimization" you are proposing. The `adb` code is pretty efficient. The overhead it introduces is very minimal. Specially in the client part. Most of the delay comes from waiting for the device's response anyway.

So stop overcomplicating things and just run multiple `adb shell` sessions. If loading the `adb` binary bothers you so much - just use sockets to talk to the `adb` server directly. Take a look at the [Mad Bee library code](http://madb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Managed.AndroidDebugBridge/Managed.AndroidDebugBridge/AdbHelper.cs) to see how to do it in `c#`. Or just use the library.

As for optimizing querying multiple system properties - just use `adb shell getprop` command to pull all properties at once.